# Doctrine query_cache_driver doesn't seem to cache query in symfony

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, apc

I'm either misunderstanding the [query_cache_driver](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html) or doing something wrong or missing a small footprint somewhere so I'm happy to blame myself here. When activated, even though the query is changed by user, is it not supposed to be using cached query instead of changed one? Please see the example below.

**NOTE:** I'm on `dev` mode so calling `http://my.local/app_dev.php/backend/league` and using [APC Admin](https://github.com/jithinjose2/APC-Admin) for stats.

**config_dev.yml**

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        query_cache_driver: apc
```

**THIS IS WITH NO CACHE AT ALL**

```
public function findAll()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('l')
        ->select('l')
        ->orderBy('l.name', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery();

    $qb = $qb->getResult();

    return $qb;
}

SELECT 
  l0_.id AS id0, 
  l0_.name AS name1 
FROM 
  league l0_ 
ORDER BY 
  l0_.name ASC
```

[image]
[image]

**THIS IS BEFORE CHANGING THE QUERY AND CACHE ACTIVATED**

```
public function findAll()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('l')
        ->select('l')
        ->orderBy('l.name', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->useQueryCache(true);

    $qb = $qb->getResult();

    return $qb;
}

SELECT 
  l0_.id AS id0, 
  l0_.name AS name1 
FROM 
  league l0_ 
ORDER BY 
  l0_.name ASC
```

[image]
[image]

**THIS IS AFTER CHANGING THE QUERY AND CACHE ACTIVATED**

Is this not supposed to be the same as above if the `query_cache_driver` caches the queries? As you can see both images are the same.

```
public function findAll()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('l')
        ->select('l')
        ->getQuery()
        ->useQueryCache(true);

    $qb = $qb->getResult();

    return $qb;
}

SELECT 
  l0_.id AS id0, 
  l0_.name AS name1 
FROM 
  league l0_
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: A quote from Doctrine's documentation states: `It is highly recommended that in a production environment you cache the transformation of a DQL query to its SQL counterpart. It doesn’t make sense to do this parsing multiple times as it doesn’t change unless you alter the DQL query.` Doesn't this apply to your case, since adding/removing `orderBy()` technically is altering the DQL?

Comment: When I use all three `metadata_cache_driver`, `query_cache_driver` and `result_cache_driver` in one go, only `metadata_cache_driver` and `result_cache_driver` work but not `query_cache_driver`. Also I haven't tried this on PROD environment.